# Entity Framwork using Context and Compiled Queries

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a winform-application and using EF 4.2. I read that in EF 4.2 the linq to entity-queries are autocompiled.
When calling a query I do the following:

```
 using (BVSEntities bvsContext = new BVSEntities(ConnectionString))
        {
            var person = (from sender in bvsContext.T_Absender
                          where sender.Absender_ID == id
                          select sender).First<T_Absender>();
            return person;
        }
```

Questions:
1) Is this query auto-compiled?
2) If it's autocompiled. Is the compiled query reused because the bvsContext is disposed after the using?
3) If not, how can I reuse it but don't get any concurrency-problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this query auto-compiled?

No because EF 4.2 doesn't include autocompiled queries. It was supposed that EF 4.2 will include them but after that naming conventions for EF has changed. Autocompiled queries are part of .NET 4.5. EF 4.2 is just EF 4.1 with some fixes.

> Is the compiled query reused because the bvsContext is disposed after the using?

.NET 4.5 contains internal cache for autocompiled queries to reuse them.

Comment: Does that mean if I update to EF 4.5 I can use the obove style and the compiled query will be reused?